# Basic bootstrap issues with data-toggle and data-target

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning how to build a simple bootstrap page using the following tutorials (very good tutorials for beginners) but I'm faced with a couple of issues which having searched around I can't seem to find a direct solution.

Just to mention I've followed the tutorial letter for letter specifically in the bits I'm having a specific issues with but to no avail.

First when resizing and then clicking the button the div doesn't drop down as expected. It seems the data-ratget for the button i.e.

```
data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse"
```

isn't targeting the folowing div:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
```

Secondly my drop down bit isn't behaving as expected i.e. the code below seems not to be toggling the unordered list

```
class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"
```

Any ideas as to why I could be facing the issues below.

The image below is what I'm trying to achieve for the dropdown.

[image: Desired result.]

Here's my code so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>      
        <title>LEARNING BOOTSTRAP</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">       
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- navbar-inverse: color change.
             navbar-static-top: remains does not fixed when scrolling
             navbar-brand: 
        -->
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top"/>

            <!-- container: -->
            <div class="container">
                <div>
                    <!-- navbar-brand: provides styling for the title -->                   
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Site title</a>

                    <!-- collapse:  
                         navHeaderCollapse links with navHeaderCollapse in the div below
                         icon-bar: built in bootstrap icons representing 3 bars
                    -->
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                                              
                    </button>

                    <!-- navHeaderCollapse: Serves as an ID -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                        <!-- nav navbar-nav: provide styling for navigation bar
                             navbar-right: right alignment
                             active: class active is used for majority of bootstrap buttons. Slightly darker and indented
                         -->
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                            <li class="active"><a href="#">NAV OPTION 1</a></li>

                            <li><a href="#">NAV OPTION 2</a></li>

                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <!-- Toggle the class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                                     class="caret": use this to for the drop down icon
                                -->
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">NAV OPTION 3 - DROP DOWN<b class="caret"></b></a>

                                <!-- To contain drop downs -->
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">DROP DOWN - NAV OPTION</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">DROP DOWN - NAV OPTION</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">DROP DOWN - NAV OPTION</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

        <h1>Hello World!</h1>

        </div>          
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the javascript file bootstrap.js in the head section of your HTML or those types of things won't work.